# what is a topical qubit and how do they correct each other?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

In an article I read " What sets company X apart are topical qubits that correct each other."

Google did not return results for "topical qubit".

Can someone explain the topical qubit - assuming that I understand how qubits operate? How do they correct each other?

Comment: There's no such thing as a *"topical qubit."* Company X plans to make "*topological qubits."* And they don't actually *"correct each other,"* either, although topological qubits do have better error-correction properties than the other technologies people are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to me to be a typographical error.  It should be **topological**, not topical, qubit.  In a nutshell, the idea is to employ the quantum states of different, more exotic microscopic systems composed of *anyons*.

See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_computer